# Error of unidentified method in form - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I did find similar questions but could not quite find a good answer, so here's my question

I keep getting this method error when trying to go into localhost:3000/clients/1/precios/new (the error comes from the _form.html.erb)

First of all *routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  #resources :precios
  #resources :catalogos
  resources :clients do
    #resources :catalogs, shallow: true
    resources :remissions, shallow: true 
    resources :catalogos
    resources :precios
    
  end

  resources :catalogs do 
      resources :products, shallow: true do
        resources :prices, shallow: true
      end
    end
  

  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out  ' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'home#index', as: 'home'

  get 'new' => 'clients#new', as: 'alta_cliente'
  
  get 'clients#index' => 'clients#index', as: 'lista_clientes'

  get 'remissions#index' => 'remissions#new', as: 'nueva_remision'
end
```

And this is the error I keep getting

```
undefined method `precios_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000d1f7018>:0x000000000a18fc90>
Did you mean?  price_path

Extracted source (around line #2):
<div class="alta-form-container">
  <%= form_with(model: precio, local: true) do |form| %> (Error in this line)
    <% if precio.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(precio.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this precio from being saved:</h2>
```

And this is my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="alta-form-container">
  <%= form_with(model: precio, local: true) do |form| %>
    <% if precio.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(precio.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this precio from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
          <% precio.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :precio %>
      <%= form.number_field :precio %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :client_id %>
      <%= form.text_field :client_id %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :catalogo_id %>
      <%= form.text_field :catalogo_id %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

What is it that I need to change in the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have following code in routes

```
resources :clients do
    resources :precios
end
```

So you need both `clients` as well as `precios` object, try following

```
<%= form_with(model: [client, precio], local: true) do |form| %>
```

Note:- You should have access to the `client` object in `_form.html.erb`